# cookie persistence with DefaultHttpClient and Swingworker

Tags: java, swing, cookies, swingworker, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a swingworker class calling a method that uses DefaultHttpClient to establish a persistent connection to a secure web site.  After I login and make a request to the site with an instance of swingworker, the instance of swingworker closes (as is normal).  My question is: how do I maintain the persistent login to the site so I can make a future request with another instance of swingworker - without logging into the site again (I have created a session)?  I cannot pass an instance of DefaultHttpClient to the swingworker class (at least I don't know how).
I have considered saving the cookie data to a file and then passing it the the DefaultHttpClient... but am I missing something more fundamental?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any parameter you want to the constructor of your [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) subclass, as suggested in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata), and you can do so with each invocation.

Comment: Just as I thought, I was missing something very fundamental.  Thank you.